# Rigged RNG Name Picker in Python 3.x

Tags: python, random, project

I have a mate who is moving into a new flat who has asked if it was possible to build a 'rigged' on demand name picker for the flat rooms. I have built this so far but I am getting errors for cyclomatic complexity (I can understand that, there's like 30 if/else loops in a row). I was just wondering what the proper way to go about assigning random numbers to integers, comparing them and then listing them in ascending order to a string.

The program should give anyone who enters a capital 'R' as their name a lower score therefore printing out that they choose the room last, once compared thru about 30 if/else statements to determine the which numbers are higher/lower (see below for example). The capital 'R' bit is so that you can enter everyones name in lowercase to prove the genuine randomness of the program, but then capitalize everyone's name on the real run thru (I'm sure there's sneakier techniques but its all I could come up with).

I am getting cyclomatic complexity flags from the first is/else statement so am thinking the issue may arise from here

```
    `print("Hello")
from random import seed
from random import randint
import time

flatmate1 = "zero"
flatmate2 = "zero"
flatmate3 = "zero"
flatmate4 = "zero"

first = 0
second = 0
third = 0
fourth = 0
value1 = 0 
value2 = 0
value3 = 0
value4 = 0
name1 = 0
name2 = 0
name3 = 0
name4 = 0

flatmate1 = input("Enter flatmate 1 name:")
flatmate2 = input("Enter flatmate 2 name:")
flatmate3 = input("Enter flatmate 3 name:")
flatmate4 = input("Enter flatmate 4 name:")

print("Generating random numbers")
time.sleep(2)


if flatmate1[0] == ("R"): 
    value1 = randint(1, 20)
    name1 = value1
else: name1 = randint(21, 100) 

if flatmate2[0] == ("R"): 
    value2 = randint(1, 20)
    name2 = value2
else: name2 = randint(21, 100) 

if flatmate3[0] == ("R"): 
    value3 = randint(1, 20)
    name3 = value3
else: name3 = randint(21, 100) 

if flatmate4[0] == ("R"): 
    value4 = randint(1, 20)
    name4 = value4
else: name4 = randint(21, 100) 

print(name1, name2, name3, name4)
print(flatmate1, flatmate2, flatmate3, flatmate4)


if (name1 > name2 and name3 and name4):
    print (flatmate1 + " chooses first")
    first = 1

elif (name2 > name3 and name4 and name1):
    print (flatmate2 + " chooses first")
    first = 2

elif (name3 > name4 and name1 and name2):
    print (flatmate3 + " chooses first")
    first = 3

elif (name4 > name1 and name2 and name3):
    print (flatmate4 + " chooses first")
    first = 4

if first == 1:
    if (name2 > name3 and name4):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses second")
        second = 2

    elif (name3 > name4 and name2):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses second")
        second = 3

    elif (name4 > name2 and name3):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses second")
        second = 4    

elif first == 2:
    if (name1 > name3 and name4):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses second")
        second = 1

    elif (name3 > name4 and name1):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses second")
        second = 3

    elif (name4 > name1 and name3):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses second")
        second = 4  

elif first == 3:
    if (name1 > name2 and name4):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses second")
        second = 1

    elif (name2 > name4 and name1):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses second")
        second = 2

    elif (name4 > name1 and name2):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses second")
        second = 4

elif first == 4:
    if (name1 > name3 and name2):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses second")
        second = 1

    elif (name3 > name2 and name1):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses second")
        second = 3

    elif (name2 > name1 and name3):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses second")
        second = 2

if second == 1 and first == 2:
    if (name4 > name2):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name3 > name4):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses third")
        third = 3

elif second == 2 and first == 1:
    if (name4 > name3):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name2 > name4):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2    

elif second == 1 and first == 3:
    if (name4 > name2):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name2 > name4):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

elif second == 3 and first == 1:
    if (name4 > name2):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name2 > name4):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

elif second == 1 and first == 4:

    if (name2 > name3):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

    elif (name3 > name2):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses third")
        third = 3

elif second == 4 and first ==1:

    if (name2 > name3):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

    elif (name3 > name2):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses third")
        third = 3

elif second == 2 and first == 3:
    if (name4 > name1):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name1 > name4):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

elif second == 3 and first == 2:
    if (name4 > name1):
        print (flatmate4 + " chooses third")
        third = 4

    elif (name1 > name4):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

elif second == 2 and first == 4:
    if (name3 > name1):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses third")
        third = 3
    elif (name1 > name3):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

elif second == 4 and first == 2:
    if (name3 > name1):
        print (flatmate3 + " chooses third")
        third = 3
    elif (name1 > name3):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

elif second == 3 and first == 4:
    if (name2 > name1):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

    elif (name1 > name2):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

elif second == 4 and first == 3:
    if (name2 > name1):
        print (flatmate2 + " chooses third")
        third = 2

    elif (name1 > name2):
        print (flatmate1 + " chooses third")
        third = 1

if (name1 < name2 and name3 and name4):
    print(flatmate1 + " chooses last")
elif (name2 < name1 and name3 and name4):
    print(flatmate2 + " chooses last")
elif (name3 < name2 and name1 and name4):
    print(flatmate3 + " chooses last")
elif (name4 < name2 and name3 and name1):
    print(flatmate4 + " chooses last")

numbers = [name1, name2, name3, name4] 
numbers.sort(reverse=True) 
print(numbers)`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

*edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stack overflow. This looks like a fun little project. But yes, you have made it hopelessly too complicated! Let's look at how we can clean this up.

TLDR, your actual mistake was in the comparisons. This:

```
if (name1 < name2 and name3 and name4):
```

Will not give you what you mean. It will check the first condition, and then check whether name3 and name4 have values. What you probably mean is this:

```
if (name1 < name2 and name1 < name3 and name1 < name4):
```

But there are much better ways of sorting a list of names! I've cleaned it up and show you below.

Just some notes beforehand:
1) I understand that you had no idea where the issue is. However, before you ask a question, you should do some logging to try and isolate the problem so that you can post a simple, reproducible example.
2) Don't post links to code please. Post the code. It would be best if you can actually edit your question to fix this. This is also why you need to isolate the problem.
3) Consider using code review stack exchange.

Okay anyway here you go:

```
# Tip 1: Be careful with uninformative print messages! They will just clutter your output.
print("This is a sanity-check message. If this displays, then the program is running.")

from random import seed
from random import randint
import time

# Tip 2: in Python, you don't need to initialise variables! I've deleated all that.

# Tip 3: DRY (Don't repeat yourself!). This is the same logic four times, so let's use a list and a loop!

# This list will store all of the flatmate names
flatmates = []

# This list will store the random numbers assigned to each flatmate
flatmate_scores = []

# I'm declaring this separately (and centrally), so that you can change it easily. Always write code in a way that is 
# easiest to change (also known by the cool kids as 'agile' development).
NUMBER_OF_FLATMATES = 4

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_FLATMATES):
    flatmates.append(input("Enter the name of flatemate number " + str(i)))

print("Generating random numbers...")
time.sleep(2)


for flatmate in flatmates:
    if flatmate[0] == "R":
        # Why create a 'value' variable if you are immediately going to 
        # assign it to a 'name' variable?
        # also, 'name' was a terrible variable name for this anyway!
        score = randint(1, 20)
    else:
        score = randint(21, 100)

    flatmate_scores.append(score)


for i in range(NUMBER_OF_FLATMATES):
    print(flatmates[i], end=', score: ')
    print(flatmate_scores[i])


# Here is where you make your first actual mistake. 
# You cannot say 'if (name1 > name2 and name3)'
# You would have to say 'if (name1 > name2 and name1 > name3)'
# etc. But there is a better way.
# We will combine the names and scores into a tuple,
# (When you are more experienced, you can make a class and objects.
# but for now a tuple is an easy data structure to use). We'll 
# make the tuple using Python's zip function 

names_with_scores = zip(flatmates, flatmate_scores)

# Now we can just sort this list using a key which tells Python to sort by 
# The second element (x[1]), which is the flatmate score:

names_with_scores = sorted(names_with_scores, key=lambda x:x[1])

# Reverse so high score means good.
names_with_scores = reversed(names_with_scores)
print("Flatmates should choose in the following order:")
for name, _ in names_with_scores:
    print(name)

# And boom. If you ignore comments, this is about 5X shorter than your original script,
# and much easier to understand.
```

Comment: Just FYI if this fails to run, I am on Python 3.8. Don't know what you use.

Comment: Wow that is awesome! Haha I do endeavor to improve my coding skills/ knowledge. 1. Indeed, I thought it was the cyclomatic complexity of the first if/else that you pointed out but thought it may be all of them it just couldnt debug past the first one? 2. Noted. It said in the description not to post if it was too long though? how long is too long? 3. Cheers, I will look into this. I was using an online compiler that stated it was just using Python 3? but i can certainly find a more up to date one. Again thanks very much!

Comment: I knew my original code was inefficient but I couldn't have imagined you could cut it down to 15ish lines!

Comment: Thank you for the comments throughout the code also, it makes it a breeze to read